# ZfcUser extend User class with additional get function

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm new to the Zend2 Framework and have installed ZfcUser with an added database column which I would like to access through:

```
<?php echo $this->zfcUserIdentity()->getOrg(); ?>
```

Any help on extending the User Class to access this variable would be greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the ZfcUser user entity to include your new property and accessors. You'll need to do this in your own module, or if you're using the skeleton app, in the `Application` module will work.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;

use ZfcUser\Entity\User;

class MyUser extends User
{
    protected $org;

    public function setOrg($org)
    {
        $this->org = $org;
        return $this;
    } 

    public function getOrg()
    {
        return $this->org;
    } 
}
```

Copy `vendor/ZfcUser/config/zfcuser.global.php.dist` to `/config/autoload/zfcuser.global.php`

Open the file you just copied in your editor, and find the section below

```
 /**
 * User Model Entity Class
 *
 * Name of Entity class to use. Useful for using your own entity class
 * instead of the default one provided. Default is ZfcUser\Entity\User.
 * The entity class should implement ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface
 */
//'user_entity_class' => 'ZfcUser\Entity\User',
```

uncomment the line, and replace the value with the fully qualified class name of the `MyUser` entity you created

```
'user_entity_class' => 'Application\Entity\MyUser',
```

Then try accessing your method

```
<?php echo $this->zfcUserIdentity()->getOrg(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was leaving out the setOrg function.